# Flutter: “ flutter build ios --release -v ” failed and show Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code . SOS

Tags: flutter-packages

I was using VSCode to archive an ios .ipa. When I tried "flutter build ios --release", it failed with message: " Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code". I google this error and found many solutions, but none of them works for me. These solutions refer to "Key Chain Access","delete pods and clean build folder" and so on. I even update my MacOS system and 'XCode' to the newest version, but no miracle happens.
Finally I found an useful command "flutter build ios --release -v" to show the detail info, here is the log on VSCode:

```
[   +6 ms] Encountered error while building for device.
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _BuildIOSSubCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:277:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

It seems like something wrong with my dart SDK, I'll be appreciate anyone helps me.

PS: This strange error only shows in my own MacBook Pro, it packages smoothly when I run the build command in my company's MacBook Pro.

Comment: Did you run the project on an android emulator?

Comment: Thank you, I never run the project on an android emulator, but I can package an android apk and install it on real android device. The apk just runs fine.

Comment: It can runs both on iOS simulator and my iPhone.

Comment: Strange，ha? This error only happens when I try packing an iOS ipa

Comment: I have never been faced with a strange issue like this. I think removing SDK and reinstalling it or restarting Vs code can fix it. When you solve your Question please let me know what the issue was.

Comment: This problem bothers me for few weeks. Removing and reinstalling SDK is my last hope and I am doing so.

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper Hi, I solved this issue just now. I deleted flutter sdk and reinstalled. After that I got another error with message "Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS". I restart my Mac and : 1.run "flutter clean" command; 2.delete Pods, podfile.lock, .xcworkspace; 3. run "flutter pub get" and "pod install"(seems unnecessary); 4. run "flutter build ios --release" and this time it success! So I guess the problem lies in flutter sdk. Anyone who encountered this problem can try delete and reinstall flutter sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try running the command:

```
flutter clean

rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework

flutter build ios --release
```

OR uninstall flutter's SDK and try reinstall it again.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the command but still get the error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code".  I'll try your last suggestion and see if it works ): .

Comment: I solve this problem with your last suggestion "uninstall flutter and reinstall it", Thanks!

Comment: that's fine....